# ViewModelProviders is deprecated in 2.2.0

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

Currently I update `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions` version from `2.2.0-alpha01` to `2.2.0`and it shows that ViewModelProviders is depricated. So what is the alternative way to use **ViewModelProviders** in kotlin?

Comment: `ViewModelProvider(this).get(ChatViewModel::class.java)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders), you can now simply use the [`ViewModelProvider` constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#public-constructors_1) directly.  It should be mostly a matter of changing `ViewModelProviders.of(` to `ViewModelProvider(`, but you can see the complete listing of exactly which new methods correspond to which old ones in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders#public-methods) as well.

In Kotlin, you can also use the `by viewModels()` property delegate within your `Activity`/`Fragment` to get individual `ViewModel`s. For example:

```
val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

Answer (score 12):

> older version

```
var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BaseViewModel::class.java)
```

> Now alternative
>
> In java

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);
```

> In kotlin

```
var  viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel::class.java)
```

Refs - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Comment: in Java "viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);"

Answer (score 8):

For example, if you are using an older version.

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), "Your string parameter")).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

For Example, for the latest version

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

OR, Use ViewModelStore [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore)

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(), viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
```